# GitHub Actions pull request checks on deployment status

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I'm experimenting with the Deployments API and would like to trigger a workflow after the deployment is successful. This should work with the `deployment_status` event. But then the workflow run does not show up in the Pull Request Checks.

Is there a way to trigger a workflow with a `deployment_status` and have the result be a requirement for a Pull Request?

[image: pr status checks]

Comment: You can use the Deployment API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/deployments?apiVersion=2022-11-28), doesn't need to be a 3rd party service.

Comment: True. That's just how the documentation describes its purpose. I suspect the wording may change when the feature is out of Alpha. One interesting factoid though is that, if you call the deployment statuses api using the builtin GitHub Actions token (`${{ github.token }}`) it will not trigger the  `on: [deployment_status]` workflow!

Comment: That's good to know! I created a PAT as I'm using this in Google Cloud Build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflows which run on `on_deployment` for deployments associated with the PR will show up in the status checks.

Suppose you have a workflow file called `status.yml` like so:

```yaml
on:
  deployment_status

jobs:
  status:
    name: status
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: on-deploy-status
      run: |
        echo "Hello workflow"
```

When you have a third party deployment that updates the deployment status, it will trigger the `status.yml` workflow for every update to the deployment status.

[image: workflow]

Unfortunately, you cannot specify the workflow to only trigger for certain statuses. The workflow will trigger for all statuses (but only the latest run on the workflow will apply). For instance, if your deployment is first updated with "in_progress" then "success", your workflow will be triggered twice with each status, but only the last run (the success status) will affect the final status checks.

You can, however, condition **jobs** (or steps) in the workflow on the status with an `if:` conditioned on `${{ github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success' }}` -- or however you want to do it.

```yaml
on: 
  deployment_status
jobs:
  status:
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success' }}
    # ...
```

Comment: Wow that was a lot simple. I thought the `deployment_status` event is not connected to the PR. Thank you.